# Dynamically change field's key name in JSON using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have one DTO with two field Like 'name' and 'id' . And I want to use name field as name key in one request and same name field as firstName key in other request.

Comment: Could you detail a bit more, or show what you have, and what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u have to create 2 DTOs:

```
 public class PersonTechnicDTO {

       @JsonProperty("key")
       String name;

      //Getter & Setter
```

```
 public class PersonDTO {
       @JsonProperty("firstName")
       String name;

     //Getter & Setter
```

In PersonDTO you get:

```
{
  "key":"Parita"
}
```

In the Person2DTO you will get:

```
{
 "firstName":"Parita"
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for replying...but I don't want to create two DTO just because of key name in JSON request...Is there any other solution?